# sklearn OneHotEncoder broken- ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I took this example from the sklearn OneHotEncoder documentary page:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)
enc.categories_

enc.transform([['Female', 1], ['Male', 4]]).toarray()

enc.inverse_transform([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

enc.get_feature_names()
```

I get:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'.

When I replace "Male" and "Female" with numbers:
`X = [['5', 1], ['4', 3], ['4', 2]]`

I get :

> AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'categories_'

My sklearn version is 0.19.1
Can someone reproduce this?

Comment: You are using an older version in which OneHotEncoder did not have the capability to directly turn strings to one-hot encoded features and seems like you are following the tutorial for latest one. You will need to use LabelEncoder first. Or else upgrade your scikit-learn and then use OneHotEncoder.

Comment: Try to use LabelEconder first and then apply one-hot encoding to its result

Comment: @VivekKumar you are right. After upgrading to 0.20.1 it works. I didn't expect that they changed the OneHotEncoder interface. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  Vivek Kumar stated 0.19.1 is too old.
Upgrading to version 0.20.1  solved the problem